# Angular 4/5 - route paramMap vs params

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get URL param in my Angular 5 app and I've found two ways of doing it:

1) Using `paramMap`

```
    ngOnInit() {
      this.hero$ = this.route.paramMap
        .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
          this.service.getHero(params.get('id')));
    }
```

2) Using `params`

```
    ngOnInit() {
      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
      });
    }
```

Is there any difference? Which one is the best practice?

Comment: Use of `switchMap` with `activatedRoute.paramMap` is no longer required after this [PR#25740](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/b7baf632c0161692f15d13f718329ab54a0f938a).  
Before this PR, it was possible for multiple navigations to run at once and hence `switchMap` was used to get the most recent navigation. With this PR, now only one active navigation will exist at a given time.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

## September 2021 update

The following answer is no longer true, and the [Angular team says](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/43529#issuecomment-926026010):

> There are no current plans to remove `params` or `queryParams` and there's no benefit to advising against their use.

## Obsolete answer

According to the documentation :

> Two older properties are still available. They are less capable than their replacements, discouraged, and may be deprecated in a future Angular version.
>
> *params* — An Observable that contains the required and optional parameters specific to the route. Use **paramMap** instead.

Simple and efficient !

Comment: params and queryParams use javaScript way (ex: params.['id'] ). paramMap and queryParamMap use TypeScript way (ex: paramMap.get['id'])

Comment: For reference, here's a link to said documentation: [router - activated route](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route).
That's a link to the router feature guide.

Unfortunately, the reference documentation of the [ActivatedRoute.params property](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#params) does not say its use is discouraged in favor of `paramMap`

Answer (score 22):

## September 2021 update

The following answer is no longer true, and the [Angular team says](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/43529#issuecomment-926026010):

> There are no current plans to remove `params` or `queryParams` and there's no benefit to advising against their use.

## Obsolete answer

Actually there is no difference but **[`params`](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route)** is  pretty old and may be deprecated soon

**paramMap**

> An Observable that contains a map of the required and optional
> parameters specific to the route. The map supports retrieving single
> and multiple values from the same parameter.

**queryParamMap**

> An Observable that contains a map of the query parameters available to
> all routes. The map supports retrieving single and multiple values
> from the query parameter.

Answer (score 17):

**Note :**
The  **paramMap** provide more convenience to play with route parameter.
Having following three methods:

1. has()
2. get()
3. getAll()

**has() :**

```js
this.router.navigate(['example', id]); 

this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params.has('id')); // true
})
```

**get() :**

```js
this.router.navigate(['example', "id","another ID"]); 

this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params.get('id'));
})
```

**getAll() :**

```js
this.router.navigate(['example', { foo: ['bar', 'baz'] } ]);

this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params.getAll('foo'));
})
```